# Tampermonkey script to text change

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I have a webpage using javascript to display links. But I want to easy copy the links, so I need to search and replace all lines like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="question-link" data-question-id="34144011">Error 1606 while installation</a>
```

by this:

```
 <a href="htt ps://www.domain.com/?qid=34144011">Error 1606 while installation</a>
```

Any help? It's my first script, but I could not do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example given, here is an example

```js
// <a href="javascript:;" class="question-link" data-question-id="34144011">Error 1606 while installation</a>

// assuming there are a number of such links with class="question-link"

document.querySelectorAll('a.question-link').forEach(a => 
  a.href = 'https://www.example.com/?qid=' + a.dataset.questionId);
```